# SwiftUI: Remove shadow from page in UIPageViewController

Tags: swiftui, uipageviewcontroller

I'm having a little issue customizing the page shadow in a UIPageViewController. Essentially, I'd like to customize it and reduce the opacity, but I'm out of ideas. Any constructive suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

```
struct PageView<T>: UIViewControllerRepresentable where T: Hashable {
    ...

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIPageViewController {
        let uiview = UIPageViewController(
            transitionStyle: transitionStyle,
            navigationOrientation: .horizontal
        )
        uiview.view.backgroundColor = .clear
        uiview.dataSource = context.coordinator
        uiview.delegate = context.coordinator
        return uiview
    }
    ...
}
```